# switching window keyboard shortcut with screen window management on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

all

I used to be a linux user, now I am accessing a server from MacOS, Ventura. I have remapped my Mac Keyboard by switching the ctrol and command keys. However, I came across some problems with the terminal shortcuts.

For example, when I ssh into a server and use `screen` for window management. I am unable to use `Ctrl-A N` to switch windows. `CMD-A N` also doesn't work. I am using the default .screenrc file.

I have similar problems when interrupting terminal process using `Ctrl-C`. Although my keyboard config shows `Ctrl-C` is the correct command to interrupt. It doesn't work. I also tried `CMD/Ctrl-C/Z/.` None of them works.

I am not sure what causes this problem.